# understanding differences of two types of differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following two types of differential equation: The first one:

\begin{align}
\dot x(t)=A(t)x(t),\; x(t)\in\mathbb R^n, x(t_0)=x_0,  A(t)\in \mathbb R^{n\times n}
\end{align}

and the second one: for $\sigma(t):\mathbb R\to \mathcal{I}$ is piecewise constant with
locally finitely many switches, $\mathcal{I}$ is finite or infinite index set:
\begin{align}
\dot x(t)=A_{\sigma(t)}x(t),\; x(t)\in\mathbb R^n, A_{\sigma(t)}\in \mathbb R^{n\times n}, x(t)\in (t_k, t_{k+1}), x(t_{0^{-}})=x_0
\end{align}

My question is what would be some of the main differences in solution trajectories of both above, some intuitive remark is also fine to get some idea. Is it possible to construct a [fundamental matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_matrix_(linear_differential_equation)) for the second type? Thank you.

Comment: Concerning your piecewise equation, do you mean this: $A(\sigma(t))$; $I=\cup_{k=0}^K (t_k,t_{k+1})$, for some $K$; $t\in (t_k, t_{k+1})$, $x(t_0)=x_0$ (what is $t_0^-$?)? Also, do you have a continuity condition on $x$ at the endpoint of each interval; is the matrix $A$ piecewise differentiable, or just continuous? In other words, am I understanding this correctly: you solve the system on an interval $I$, where $A$ is piecewise differentiable (continuous?) and are looking for a continuous solution? These questions might be the consequence of my non-understanding some lingo such as "switches".

Comment: Here is the reference for $t_0^{-}$ and your doubt about continuity condition http://research.stephantrenn.de/tl_files/Preprints/Preprint-TW120901.pdf

Comment: What it is meant by a matrix piecewise differentiable, or continuous?

Comment: Sorry, the correct notation will be $x(t_{0^{-}})$

Comment: Just like "piecewise constant", "piecewise differentiable/constant" loosely means that it is differentiable/continuous  on the different pieces that makes the domain. Thank you for the article but I just don't quite understand the notation. Perhaps because I am not in this field of study.

Comment: OK, Thank you for your reply.

Comment: What is a notion of solution to $x'(t) = A(t)x(t)$ if $A$ is discontinuous in $t$? In that case, the ODE won't even be defined. Something similar happens in the second case. The second case is special because although the right hand side is discontinuous at some points, it is still possible to reasonably define a notion of solution and prove uniqueness/existence etc. (using forward propagation). Such results are not clear for the first equation, when $A$ is discontinuous. That's the key *analytic* difference. As for trajectories, not that depends on what kind of function $A(t)$ is.